# Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key

Tags: java, spring, boot

Any one help me with this below error

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Could not load key store 'null'

i have placed the key store file out side the project . i check key file also using keytool list command. Still application not starting .

i am using java 11 , maven 3.6.3 . spring boot 2.3.2 release

i did not find any solutions for it .

but i tried loading keystore inside the project , outside, adding new key file . northing works .

Comment: can you provide your application configuration

Comment: Can you provide us with your full pom.xml file;

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was fixed after adding the keystore properties to management port .

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
         include: ["health", "info", "metrics", "prometheus", "bindings", "beans", "env", "loggers","actuator"]
      base-path: /
      path-mapping:
        prometheus: metrics
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
  server:
    port: ${npbprog.metrics.server.port}
    ssl:
      enabled: true 
       key-store: ${ssl.key-store}
    key-store-type: ${ssl.key-store-type}
    key-store-password: ${ssl.key-store-password}
    key-password: ${ssl.key-password}
    key-alias: ${ssl.key-alias}
    protocol: TLS 
    enabled-protocols: 
    - TLSv1.2
```